# Por que a posição "Landscape" não redimensiona o LongListSelector?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, layout, xaml

Por que quando coloco o celular na posição Landscape, o `LongListSelector`não se redimensiona?

Segue a imagem:

[image: Landscape]

Segue meu `XAML`

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <phone:LongListSelector Name="lstConsPais"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LayoutMode="List" IsGroupingEnabled="False" SelectionChanged="lstConsPais_SelectionChanged">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#222" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
                            <Image Height="100" Width="100"  Source="{Binding NomeImgBandeira}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NomePais}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,25,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
```

Quando eu tiro o `width` a lista não aparece mais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Eu queria que ele preenchesse a tela toda.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria uma forma de alterar as configurações da tela:

Meio automático:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <!--You must apply a background to the StackPanel control or you
    will be unable to pan the contents.-->
    <StackPanel Background="Transparent" >
        <!--Adding various controls and UI elements.-->
        <Button Content="This is a Button" />
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Margin="12,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Margin="12,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="This is a line of text that will wrap in portrait
            orientation but not landscape orientation." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <CheckBox Content="A CheckBox"/>
        <RadioButton Content="A RadioButton" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Referência site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (todos direitos autorais ao site msdn.microsoft.com).

---

**Ou**

*Reescreva esse método*

```
protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape)
            {

            }
            else if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Portrait)
            {

            }
            base.OnOrientationChanged(e);
}
```

*Ou o próprio metodo*

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape)
            {

            }
            else if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Portrait)
            {

            }
 }
```

Nesse [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) tem a explicação detalhada.

***Exemplo***

Esse exemplo funcionou o `Portrait` e `Landscape` como você espera.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.Page3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Landscape"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <!--You must apply a background to the StackPanel control or you
    will be unable to pan the contents.-->
                <StackPanel Background="Transparent" >
                    <!--Adding various controls and UI elements.-->
                    <Button Content="This is a Button" />
                    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Margin="12,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Margin="12,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="This is a line of text that will wrap in portrait
            orientation but not landscape orientation." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <CheckBox Content="A CheckBox"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="A RadioButton" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

***Para sua solução, exemplo:***

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.Page4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded" OrientationChanged="PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged">  
    <!--Solução-->   
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">        
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>            
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="15,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="2,2,10,0">
                <phone:LongListSelector Name="lstConsPais"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LayoutMode="List" IsGroupingEnabled="False" SelectionChanged="lstConsPais_SelectionChanged">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#111" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
                                    <Image Height="100" Width="100"  Source="{Binding NomeImgBandeira}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NomePais}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="15,25,0,0" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
<!--Solução-->
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Referências:

- [OrientationChangedEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.orientationchangedeventargs%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [Quickstart: Screen orientation for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Eu vou ter que "dizer" pra ele se redimensionar? Não tem como ser tipo "automático"? Como no android.

Comment: Tem um exemplo no link que eu te passei que o primeiro caso se encaixa ao sua dúvida.

Comment: Você sabe o motivo do meu não estar redimensionando?

Comment: @Exception eu colei uma pagina que fiz aqui no meu VS Phone e deu certo... por favor olhe na resposta

Comment: realmente com seu exemplo deu certo. Mas por qual motivo o meu não da certo? Por que ele não redimensiona pra completar a tela toda?

Comment: @Exception fiz a alteração na resposta novamente e observe o item "Para sua solução, exemplo:".

Comment: Quando eu tiro o `Width` a lista não aparece mais. Atualizei a pergunta!

Comment: Exception sem o width ele não tem tamanho é por isso é como se fosse 0. Você olhou o exemplo que te passei, ele ta certinho como você queria ? dá uma olhada!

Comment: Olhei sim, copiei e colei no meu `xaml`, e não aparece a lista por causa do `width`. Se eu colocar um `tamanho`, tenho que pensar em um "dinamico" pra que ele funcione no `landscape` e no `portrait`.

Comment: @Exception é dificil falar do seu modelo ai, eu não to vendo o xaml inteiro você mandou uma parte e eu te mandei um inteiro tem diferenças viu ... olha só o seu não tem nem isso <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">