# Como apresentar app em tela cheia / fullscreen no Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xaml

Desejo que minha aplicação rode em modo de tela cheia.

Ja tentei usando os códigos abaixo, porém, estão dando alguns erros.

O código não é reconhecido pelo emulador:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
   ...
   shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
   ...
/>
```

"SystemTray" não existe no contexto atual:

```
private void OnPhoneApplicationPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
   SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
}
```

Como devo fazer?

Comment: Eu tenho um exemplo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14624/6026 que a tela redimensiona conforme posição do celular. Eu acredito ser a sua dúvida!!!

Comment: No windows 8.1 o que substitui o uso de:
 SystemTray.IsVisible = false; ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Windows 8.1 é diferente mesmo! mudou siga o código abaixo:

```
StatusBar statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
// Hide the status bar
await statusBar.HideAsync();    
//Show the status bar
await statusBar.ShowAsync();
```

*Fonte:* [SOEN - Hide Status bar in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23009689)

Referência

- [StatusBar class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar%28v=win.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Caso queira mostrar somente um dos itens da Barra de Satatus?
Como somente as horas por exemplo

Comment: Faça o seguinte @Anderson, abra um novo questionamento e coloque na sua pergunta o seu código atual, isso ajuda a mais pessoas ajudarem e ai eu dou uma resposta também, porque, eu não consigo visualizar tal dúvida, não sei se me entende nesse aspecto.